# boost::multiprecision::float128 and C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I'm trying to use `boost::multiprecision::float128` (boost 1.55.0) under C++11 (gcc 4.8.1), but get the following compiler error:

```
/cm/shared/apps/boost/gcc/1.55.0/include/boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp: In static member function ‘static std::numeric_limits<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::float128_backend, ET> >::number_type std::numeric_limits<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::float128_backend, ET> >::min()’:
/cm/shared/apps/boost/gcc/1.55.0/include/boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp:533:55: error: unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator"" Q’
    static number_type (min)() BOOST_NOEXCEPT { return 3.36210314311209350626267781732175260e-4932Q; }
```

Can't I use `boost::multiprecision::float128` in C++11? Or how else do I get it working?

**edit**

Just to clarify. This error is generated by

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>
```

The compiler is not happy with the statement

```
return 3.36210314311209350626267781732175260e-4932Q;
```

in particular the `Q` is confusing it. I used the compiler flags `-std=c++11 -fabi-version=0 -march=native -mfpmath=sse`

Comment: Can you show how you are using it?

Comment: @Swalog this error comes from the boost header file. I havn't used it yet.

Comment: The `#include` statements then. It helps when trying to recreate the problem. Perhaps also relevant linkage flags.

Comment: Tested and got the same error. The answer below also solved the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[It looks like a known issue](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9240). Try compiling with `-fext-numeric-literals`.